# Cannot prevent azure function Python cold starts

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I cannot figure out how to completely stop azure function cold starts on the dedicated or premium plans. I have a ML function returning a prediction on input data. What I've tried:

- using the Python V2 model so all code is in the same .py file (e.g. all dependencies loaded together)
- warmupTrigger (also calls the predict function so that the model is loaded/warmed up)
- swap warmup trigger (for preventing cold starts during swaps)
- health check, using different variations of the parameters for `WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXPINGFAILURES` and `WEBSITE_HEALTHCHECK_MAXUNHEALTHYWORKERPERCENT`
- adjusting `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT` and `PYTHON_THREADPOOL_THREAD_COUNT`
- using async for the prediction
- prewarmed instances on the premium plan

I added a UUID in the function app script, so that each python worker has an UUID I can track. I was using the EP3 plan with 4 python workers (FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT=4), and I can see that the warmup function is only being called on 2 of the workers upon scale-out. This means on the 2 workers that are not warm, the first few calls take 5-10s to run, which is a cold start.

I also tried setting FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT=1, using async for the function call, then setting the thread count to 4. However, this didn't seem to work as expected for utilizing the vCPU power, so the scaling didn't work well.

What else can I do to fully prevent cold-starts in a Python azure function with multiple python workers? I noticed there was some shared memory preview feature, but not sure if that could solve the issue, or if something else could.